# Reduce boot time in ionic-2 app

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am new to ionic-2 project.I just want to know how to reduce boot time of  app.Because after 3 sec of splash screen , it shows white screen and takes 9 sec to start.

Comment: there is some issues with that, you can follow them here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9686 there is also some issue in ionic-app-scripts and there is some solutions try it

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 15):

Try to put this on the second line of your `main.ts` file

`import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';`

then before the bootstrap line put

`enableProdMode();`

also when building use `--prod` so `ionic build android --prod`

Comment: what the mean of this add line in main.ts ?  Main.ts always generated after build . so We never write on main.ts file.

Answer (score 4):

Please follow below steps to reduce splash screen time:-

First, delete your node_modules folder
Delete any Temp Folder
Delete Plugins Folder
remove platform android using `ionic platform rm android`.
Now Reinstall Everything : -

(i) `npm install` (ii) `ionic serve` (iii) `ionic platform add android`

Now run this Command FINALLY `ionic build android --prod`

THIS WORKS 100% PERFECTLY.

If this doesn't work please don't give up. Try above steps 2 to 3 times, I'm SURE this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue with the white screen, check out the progress here. [Cordova, Android, incredibly slow loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309273/cordova-android-incredibly-slow-loading)

Short version is; it's loading slow due to a plethora of reasons, mentioned by Fernando above. You can work to resolve those yes, but for the white screen... Android will hide the splash screen while the app is still loading. To fix that problem you can add the below to your config;

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
```

This will ensure the splash screen remains up for at least 10 seconds while the app is loading, and not auto-hide. Then in your startup module's main component just make sure you have the below to hide the splash screen once your app actually starts up and you'll be all set. obviously requires cordova-splash-screen plugin which ships default with ionic2.

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
  Splashscreen.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. Actually, i had already done this.But the main issue is the time to boot the app that is 10 seconds.I am looking for the solution to reduce boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem. After revering ionic-team forum, I understand that ionic-team has not yet come up with any solution to this.

I made the following code which minimizes the app instead of closing it, so that when next time the app is opened it opens instantly.

Put the below code in app.component.ts file

```
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        if(this.menuCtrl.isOpen()){
           this.menuCtrl.close();
        } 
        else if(this.nav.canGoBack()){
          this.nav.pop();
        }else{
          this.appMinimize.minimize();
        }
      });
```

You may need to install @ionic-native/app-minimize

links to refer:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-minimize/

Answer (score 0):

Please enable production mode in the `main.ts` file, like this

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
enableProdMode();
```