# Ionic app shows white screen after splash for 14-15 second

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working on ionic2.Few days ago,ionic2 was updated.After splash screen,we get the white screen for 14-15 second ,due to ionic2 was updated.

Comment: @PunitGajjar i dont think there some code for that

Comment: did you find any solution @seasia creative crew

Comment: can you share package.json and which OS,device you are getting this?

Comment: This is my app.components.ts file                                         initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      
    });
  }

Comment: This is config.xml file

Answer (score 1):

there is some issues with that, you can follow them here [github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9686](http://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9686) there is also some issue in ionic-app-scripts and there is some solutions try it

Answer (score 1):

Add the `--prod` flag during any of the following CLI commands:

```
// If iOS
ionic emulate ios --prod
ionic build ios --prod
ionic run ios --prod


// If Android
ionic emulate android --prod
ionic build android --prod
ionic run android --prod
```

[More about this](http://masteringionic.com/blog/2017-02-10-improving-ionic-app-launch-times/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this in Android specific. I was having the same problem, the issue is two-fold:

1. The app is loading very slowly. If you watch console logs you'll see you get a note about it's taking 11000ms to load or whatever
2. Android is trying to be helpful by hiding the splash screen before you app is actually ready

I can't help you with #1, review your plugins, google around a bunch, and good luck. As for #2, you can add the line to config.xml to resolve

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Increase the SplashScreenDelay until you the app is reliably loaded before it hides.

- Make sure you have SplashScreen.hide() in your platform.ready function in your main module as well so that when your app actually does load it'll hide.

You can find a bit more in [Cordova, Android, incredibly slow loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309273/cordova-android-incredibly-slow-loading?noredirect=1#comment69841635_41309273)

Comment: An better options would be to NOT hide the splashscreen plugin by default, and hide it in your app.components ngONInit() using Splashscreen.hide();

Comment: I suppose you're right @JoeriShoeby ... splash.hide is of course in the platform.ready of main module as mentioned... don't know why we'd need a delay at all at that point, all the samples and solutions I've found suggest that. Good call and thanks, I've edited my answer

Comment: I'm already use the <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />  but it was not working . Can you please help me?

Comment: Also,Hide the splash in app.components.ts .But  after splash we get the white screen.Can you please help me how to hide white screen ?

Comment: @SeasiaCreativeCrew I'm not sure, for my problem I just kept messing with SplashScreenDelay until I got it working right, ended up using 10000